# D-finite function?

Tags: combinatorics, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, formal-power-series

We call a function  $f(x)\in \mathbb{C}[[x]]$ $D-finite$ if there exists a differential operator of the from 
$$ a_{i}(x)(D_x)^i + \ldots+a_{0}(x)    $$ which annihilated $f(x)$. $D_{x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $a_i (x)\in \mathbb{C}(x)$. 
For example $e^x=\sum_{d}\frac{1}{d!}x^d$ is D-finite.

I wanted to compute the Annihilator for the function
$$P(x):=1+ \sum_{d\geq1}\frac{1}{(\lfloor{\frac{d}{2}}\rfloor)!} x^{d} $$
where $\lfloor,\rfloor$ denote integer function for example $\lfloor5/2\rfloor=2$. 
RISC could not compute the annihilator for it. Is this not a $D-finite$ function?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the sum into two parts, separating even and odd values of $d$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I split the sum and then calculate the annihilator but then I don't know how to get the annihilator of the sum that is my original function.

Comment: Differentiate the sum with respect to $x$.

Comment: Yes w.r.t x. I use RISC holonomic function package. So when I write the sum as you suggested by even and odd that is  $P(x):= e^{x^2} +(e^{x^2}-1)x$ then I could use the Annihilator[P(x),Der[x]]$. What I want is to find a function in mathematica to make use of the closure properties of holonomic functions.

Comment: That's show as well this particular function I wrote is $D-fintie$ but I don't know why it should give me error given in original form.

Comment: One of us has made a small mistake splitting the sum by hand. I got the same except for the $-1$. Anyway, there is a separate forum for questions about Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks again. I see I never knew about Mathematica form.

Comment: Here's the address: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/